# How many choices for this combination?

Tags: combinations

Suppose that we a string contains n multiplicates of '-1' and '+1', we denote it $A = {\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{2n}\}}$.

Define $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i$. If, $\forall k\leq 2n, S_k \geq 0$, then how many choices for the string?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What is the relation between $n$ the number of $1's$ and $n$ the summation index?

Comment: the numbers of -1 and 1 are n correspongdingly.

Comment: Yes...but you also write $S_n$.  Is that the same $n$?

Comment: I see the edit, but I think you also meant to write "$\forall k≤2n\,S_k≥0$, no?

Comment: I believe you are asking about the [Ballot Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem)...you'll want the variant in which ties are allowed.

Comment: Yes, it indeed solves the problem, thank you!